# setInterval within onClick in React

Tags: reactjs

UPDATE: I am very new to React(and js) and playing around with it. What I want to do is that you can only click on the image every 10 secs or something. How do I do it? I am not sure where to reset isClickable.

I have something like this:

```
    Var ClickableImage = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        isClickable: false,
        counter: 0
    };
},

componentDidMount: function(){

    // componentDidMount is called by react when the component 
    // has been rendered on the page. We can set the interval here:
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            isClickable: true,
        });
    }, 1000);

},

handleClick: function() {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+1 });

},

render: function(){

    var imgStyle = {
      width: '80%',
      height: '80%',
      backgroundColor: "#4ECDC4"
    };

    var counterStyle = {
      width: '80%',
      height: '80%',
      backgroundColor: "#674172"
    };

    const optionalOnClick = this.state.isClickable ? {
        onClick: this.handleClick,
        isClickable: false
    } : {};

    return(
            <div>
            <div style = {imgStyle}> 
                <img src={this.props.src} width="100%" height="80%" onClick={this.optionalOnClick}/>
            </div>
            <div style = {counterStyle}> 
                {this.state.counter} 
            </div>

            </div>
    )
}
```

});

```
ReactDOM.render(<ClickableImage src='http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/parody/images/2/27/Minions_bob_and_his_teddy_bear_2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150507162409' />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Even though you have changed the question - solution is still very similar: after a click reset the state and set it back in the timer.

Comment: I tried to do that but its still now working. I updated what my full code looks like in the question itself. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Change your question with your actual code.

Comment: 1. You should have `{...optionalOnClick}` - it expands the object to the component properties 2. `optionalOnClick` should not have anything but `onClick` 3. After you do that you'll likely to have a problem with `this` in the click handler

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! :) So now the image is only clickable after the specified time in the setTimeout but after that you can click at anytime. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Yep, your click handler needs few modifications: 1. it must switch a component to `isClickable: false` with `setState` 2. It should set another `setTimeout` that changes the state to `isClickable: true` back.

Answer (score 2):

That's how I would do that:

```
class ClickableImage extends Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

        this.state = {
            isClickable: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                isClickable: true,
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    handleClick() {
        // ...
    }

    render() {
        const optionalOnClick = this.state.isClickable ? {
            onClick: this.handleClick,
        } : {};

        return (
            <img src={this.props.src} width="100%" height="80%" {...optionalOnClick} />
        );
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. when the component is mounted - use `setTimeout` to change the state to `isClickable: true`
2. in render function check if `isClickable` is set, if so - add a handler.

Comment: I am not familiar with ES6 so this is a little difficult for me to understand. I looked things up and tried to do it the way you suggested and I am getting a "Component is not defined" error.

Comment: Well, convert it to a non-ES6 then. The first line simply creates a component